# PHP - CodeIgniter download remote file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble with the CodeIgniter in downloading files..

The code works perfectly in alone php file, but when i put the code in CodeIgniter:
The file will download successfully, but it was damage :(.

Note: I'm working with video files from remote servers.

The code:

```
$file = fopen ($link, "r");
if (!$file) {
    echo "<p align='center' style='color:#FF0101;'>Unable to open remote file :(, Please try again in a few minutes.</p>";
}else{
    ob_clean();
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=zxc.3gp');
    //header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    //header("Content-Length: ".$video_size);


    while (!feof ($file)) {
        $line = fgets ($file, 1024);
        echo $line;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($file);
    die();
}
```

I tried this code in new CodeIgniter project:

```
public function index()
{
    $link = 'http://mamprogr.net.tc/tmp/1.3gp';
    $this->load->helper('download');
    force_download('1.3gp',$link);
}
```

But not working :(

Comment: What's the question? What's not working? Any error messages? [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: CodeIgniter [Output Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html) to the blame! See <- that page.

I have no idea how you'd solve the problem but this _is_ the problem.

Comment: Are you compressing output with gzip? If so, that is your problem. You can't output content directly from a controller method if gzip compression is enabled. You must use a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [force_download()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html) helper of CodeIgniter and see if it helps

```
force_download($name, $data);
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that you tried to provide a direct link as the second parameter to force_download() function - however, it takes "data" -- see below -

```
$data = file_get_contents("/local/path/to//1.3gp"); // Read the file's contents
//or perhpas $data = fopen(......);
$name = '1.3gp';

force_download($name, $data);
```

Comment: It might not because he'd like to specifically exploit ob_flush() property. Does force_download allow streaming is the question now.

Comment: Not working.. file downloaded, but file not working.. i'm useing remote file, not local!

Comment: @MAMProgr - you need to provide data instead of url - see my update

Answer (score 0):

Your solution solves the problem for the download. however when the file is played you will get an errro:

Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.

I tried quicktime and realplayer and still the video refuses to play.

Answer (score 0):

in my case download link on external site is `https://example.com/test.apk` I use the following and it works like charm ,codeignighter version is 4

```
return redirect()->to('https://example.com/test.apk');
```